# Fluent Nhibernate how to ignore mapping columns from an existing table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is it possible to map a class in model to a table that has more columns than the model class? I just want to map specific columns of a table using `Fluent Nhibernate`. For example the table has these columns:

```
ProductId
ProductName
BatchNumber
StoreId
```

but in the model class I just want: `ProductId`, `ProductName`.
Is it possible not to include `BatchNumber` and `StoreId` in the model class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override mapping:

```
public class ProductAutoMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Product> {

    public void Override(AutoMapping<Product> mapping) {
       mapping.Id(p => p.ProductId),
       mapping.Map(p => p.ProductName),
       mapping.IgnoreProperty(p => p.BatchNumber);
       mapping.IgnoreProperty(p => p.StoreId);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do I still need to have my ClassMap<Product> class?

Comment: @AminMohammadi No, you don't need `ClassMap<T>`. You can set FluentNHibernate to map class automatically and the `IAutoMappingOverride<T>` give you the possibility to tweak the automapped classes.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: What if I don't define BatchNumber and StoreId? will it be correctly mapped?